# JSON parsing which is have an array of items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had a JSON response as below

```
{"items":["1","2","3"],"code":"ok"}

var simpleArry = [] ;
$http.post(url, "", "")
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data.items);
                //$scope.items= response.data.items;
                //instead of the above line 
                simpleArry = resp.data.items;
            });
```

I need the array to iterate again to get some data from another call .
need it in a list/array which it should look like

```
var itmsArry = ["1","2","3"]
```

I tried something like this

```
var simpleArry = [] ;
simpleArry = resp.data.items;
```

but it always empty . What went wrong with it

My Question was not duplicate . Its about the json array and nothing to do with async call

Comment: please show more code for the request and response.

Comment: Define "empty"!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You don't have `data` in your `response`. Simply log `response.items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved .

```
var testArry = [];

for (var r = 0; r < response.data.items.length ; r++){
  testArry.push(response.data.items[r]);                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the code you showed, Probably you are assigning outside the response,

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {
  myService.getJSON().then(function(data){
            $scope.myData =data;
            console.log(data);
 });

});
app.service('myService', function($http) {
  this.getJSON = function() {
    return $http.get('test.json').then(function(data) {
      return data.data.items;
    });
  };
});
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/scjc9TLooigjq3QKPVbp?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you should try this below the code

> javascript code

```
var str='{"items":["1","2","3"],"code":"ok"}';
var data=JSON.parse(str);
console.log(data.items);
```

> output
>   [image]

Comment: Its the first thing I did and I always got SyntaxError: Invalid character

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
try{
    var data = JSON.parse(response)
}catch{

}
```

data.item contains the array.

Comment: I got the error as "SyntaxError: Invalid character"

Comment: Are you sure the response is same as that you have mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes ...Its the same format and exactly same nothing changed